# How can I exclude binaries from rgrep results in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, grep

I'd like to add the `I` option to the grep that `rgrep` generates, but I cannot seem to find the appropriate variable.

I've tried:

- `grep-command`
- `grep-find-command`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep-find-template`:

```
The default command to run for M-x rgrep.
The following place holders should be present in the string:
 <D> - base directory for find
 <X> - find options to restrict or expand the directory list
 <F> - find options to limit the files matched
 <C> - place to put -i if case insensitive grep
 <R> - the regular expression searched for.
In interactive usage, the actual value of this variable is set up
by `grep-compute-defaults'; to change the default value, use
Customize or call the function `grep-apply-setting'.
```

Set this variable to `"find . <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -nHI -e <R> {} +"` or whatever you think is appropriate.

---

To change the command for `lgrep`, similarly use `grep-template`: `"grep <X> <C> -nHI -e <R> <F>"`